# Browser-sync not reloading for file event add/change

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browser-sync

Im using browser-sync with webpack, since there are some files in the build that webpack doesnt have rules for. For some reason browser-sync is not triggering reloads when my image files are modified/added/removed?

In the terminal its logging `[BS] File event [add] : image.png` and
`[BS] File event [change] : image.png`

But unlike when I edit a .html file, its not saying `[BS] Reloading Browsers...`

This is my browser-sync init:

`browserSync.init({
    files: ['./**.html', './**.png']
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to pass a custom event handler to browserSync.init files option, that responded to any kind of events with a reload()

example:

```
browserSync.init({
        files: [
            {
                match: ['./img/**'],
                fn:    function (event, file) {
                    this.reload()
                }
            }
        ]
    })
```

Comment: Would the `--no-inject-changes` param do that for you?

Answer (score 2):

By default BroswerSync only listens for `change` events. The [`watchEvents`](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-watchEvents) option can be changed to listen to `add`ing of files. Add `add`, `unlink`, `addDir` and `unlinkDir` to listen to adding and removing of files and directories.

```
browserSync.init({
    files       : [ './img/**' ]
    watchEvents : [ 'change', 'add', 'unlink', 'addDir', 'unlinkDir' ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the browser-sync code base, BS will either perform a page refresh (aka browser reload) or the file changes will be injected. BS performs injection for files with the following extensions: "css", "gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "svg", "webp", "map".

If you want to disable code injection for all file types, then set the `injectChanges` config to false. Or add the `--no-inject-changes` command line flag. This option will turn off injection for all file types.

If you still want to allow code injection for a subset of the file types listed above, then remove `injectChanges` config or set it to false. Also, remove the `--no-inject-changes` if set. Then add entries in the `files` array for the files requiring browser reload. For example:

```
files: [
    {
        match: ['./img/**'],
        fn:    function (event, file) {
            this.reload()
        },
    },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution that worked for me is `injectChanges:false`

Check docs page: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-injectChanges

so try this:

```
browserSync.init({
  injectChanges: false,
  files: ['./**.html', './**.png']
});
```

of for those who use Laravel Mix (like I do):

```
mix.browserSync({
  injectChanges: false,
  files: ['./**.html', './**.png']
});
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want watch all HTML files in current directory use `./*.html` or `*.html`

`**` — it's subdirectory; `*` — it's files in directory

Examples:

- `./**/*.html` — watch in all subdirectory files with extension `html`
- `app/js/*.js` — watch in directory `app/js` all files with extension `js`

More information about [Browsersync options](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options)

Comment: did you see the browser-sync init() i posted? it already **is** watching html files, and its also detecting png files, just not reloading the browser

`'./**.html', './**.png'` - when there is a .html and a .png in the *same* directory, if i edit the .html file, browser-sync reloads the browser, however if i edit a .png that is right next to the .html file, it doesnt reload the browser, it merely logs `[BS] File event [change] : image.png`

so its detecting the png and the html files in the same folder, its just not triggering a browser reload for the pngs, like it is with the html

Comment: Can you add your files structure in question?

Comment: its just a directory in the root folder `./img/` and it contains 2 files right now for testing purposes - `./img/index.html` and `./img/image.png`.

as i said, edits to `./img/index.html` trigger a browser reload, edits to `./img/image.png` cause browser-sync to log  `[BS] File event [change] : image.png` to the terminal, but unlike when i edit the .html, it doesnt log `[BS] Reloading Browsers...`